# Laravel echo - could not be authenticated to private Channel

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am trying to authenticate the laravel echo using a private channel. Every time I am getting "could not be authenticated to private-basket_details.1 " . "basket_details" this is the channel name and 1 is the parameter.

When I use a public channel everything works perfectly. So I think there are some issues with the auth part.

This is my error log

```
⚠ [14:42:55] - 5eKrT28nX7uLHEkLAAAG could not be authenticated to private-basket_details.1
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/Laravel/uneek_clothing/trunk/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 179,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/Laravel/uneek_clothing/trunk/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 612,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/Laravel/uneek_clothing/trunk/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 601,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
```

This is my Event file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use App\Basket;
use App\User;

class UpdateWebOrderDetailsToBasket implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $basket;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Basket $basket)
    {
        $this->basket = $basket;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('basket_details.'.$this->basket->id);
    }

}
```

This is my channels.php

```
<?php
// use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/

Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

// Broadcast::PrivateChannel('basket.{basketId}', function ($user, $basketId) {
//     return true;
// });

// Broadcast::channel('basket_details.1', function ($user, $basketId) {
//     return true;
// });

Broadcast::channel('basket_details.{basketId}', function ($user, $basketId) {
    return true;
});

// Broadcast::channel('private-basket_details.*', function ($user, $basketId) {
//     return true;
// });
```

This is my js file

```
Echo.private('basket_details.1')
    .listen('.App\Events\UpdateWebOrderDetailsToBasket', (e) => {
      console.log("channel started here");
    });
```

This is my BroadcastServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

This is my laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "http://192.168.1.120:1002",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "be17370a567448f7",
            "key": "7af893ebfa188744e6317b30a481824f"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "9999",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "http://192.168.1.120:9999",
        "allowMethods": "GET,POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

Comment: same problem, hadn't it before. did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, used a public channel @Shadrix

Comment: as of today, still not a solution? @AravindSrinivas I just stumbled upon this issue as well.
I'm a total noob in this topic, what would be the cons of using Channel instead of PrivateChannel in this case?

Comment: I had to move my `socket.io-client` from version `3.*` to `2.2.0`. For me that was the problem the entire time. Had nothing to do with `Laravel` or `laravel-echo-server`

Answer (score 5):

did you forgot to uncomment BroadcastServiceProvider::class in config/app.php

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class
```

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that sticks that may be problematic is the event namespace you're listening on. The docs show using dot notation as opposed to backslashes:

```
Echo.private('basket_details.1')
  // change this to '.App.Events.UpdateWebOrderDetailsToBasket' 
  // or just 'UpdateWebOrderDetailsToBasket' since you are using the default App\Events.
  .listen('.App\Events\UpdateWebOrderDetailsToBasket', (e) => {
    console.log("channel started here");
  });
```

See [Namespaces](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#namespaces)

Can you verify the correct authorization route is being reached? Does any thing print if you log from:

```
Broadcast::channel('basket_details.{basketId}', function ($user, $basketId) {
    logger('Basked ID: ' . $basketId);
    return true;
});
```

If you are protecting these routes using the api middleware, for example, you'll need to create the Echo instance with the proper headers:

```
const client = new Echo({
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Logger not logging,

I' m not using any api's

Comment: The `NotFoundHttpException` might reveal the issue, try logging the exception from `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to see if a more informative message or stack trace prints.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to your HTML / Layout and that should fix your problem in must cases.